# Palatino with text figures, not in math mode or headings

Tags: math-mode, xetex

I'm working on a document which is fairly math-heavy, but also contains numbers outside of math mode. I want these numbers to be displayed as old-style/text figures. I also want a Palatino-type font (either `mathpazo` or `tgpagella`). Using `tgpagella` with `textcomp` gives me text figures, but then math mode is displayed in the regular Computer Modern font. Using `mathpazo` with the `[osf]` option gives me text figures everywhere---even in titles, headings, and math mode, where they don't belong. I can't seem to figure out how to mix text and lining figures with Palatino-like math fonts.

Comment: Are you sure that with the `[osf]` option of `mathpazo`, you get text figures in math mode? I agree with the fact that you get text figures in titles, but not in math mode.

Comment: With `\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}` you certainly get text figures in titles and headers, and certainly *not* in math mode. If you want lining figures in titles and headers, you should tell more about the document class you're using.

Answer (score 2):

This is a XeLaTeX solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load mathpazo as a math font
\usepackage{mathpazo}

% Load Pagella as a text font by specifying no-math to fontspec
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}

Some numbers outside math mode: 1 2 3 4 5

Some numbers in math mode: $1 2 3 4 5$

\end{document}
```

It works the same for headers (use math-mode if you don't want old-style figures).

Edit: OSF are fine in headers and titles unless you write them in full capital letters (by contrast to roman, bold, italic and small-caps). Automatically putting lining figures there would require quite a bit more work (such as redefining the section headers) and I don't quite think it is worth it – especially since the result would *not* be typographically correct.